# fbounds checking not working, any replacement?

Tags: c, makefile, bounds-checker

I was trying to get the fbounds checking to work, but I did not succeed. I get a following error:

> /tmp/cczxKZzn.s: Assembler messages:
>
> /tmp/cczxKZzn.s:48: Error: invalid instruction suffix for `push'
>
> /tmp/cc9xD8T3.s:125: Error: invalid instruction suffix for `pop'

while my makefile looks like this (with simple makefile everything is compiling properly):

```
all: error check

error: error.c
    /usr/local/gcc-4.0.2/bin/gcc -fbounds-checking -g -Wall -pedantic $< -o $@

.PHONY: clean check

clean:
    -rm error

check:  error
    ./error
```

Since that code has nothing to do with assembler, I don't know what to do. Assembler problems are the only ones I can see in my google search on that topic.

---

Can You propose other solutions checking for example for being outside an array?
Such as (this is my error.c):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
  int a[1][10];
  a[0][11]=42;
  return 0;
}
```

---

EDIT. Can it be a version incompatibility; gcc 4.4+ is installed and I'm doing that with path to a little modified gcc 4.0.2 ?

Comment: There's no such thing as "fbounds". -f means "flag", so it's the bounds-check flag.

Comment: @JimBalter after changing to "-bounds-check" it doesn't work as well.

Comment: I didn't say anything about changing it to "-bounds-check". Please read what I wrote again. It's "-f" + "bounds-check" = "-fbounds-check". The point is, as I said, that there's no such thing as "fbounds checking", which is what it says in your title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since that code has nothing to do with assembler, I don't know what to
>   do. Assembler problems are the only ones I can see in my google search
>   on that topic.

Looks like you're invoking the wrong assembler - a 32 bit one, trying to compile a 64bit object code. Check your PATHs and flags.

**UPDATE**: I never looked into how exactly gcc invokes its components. It's still not very clear to me. Anyway, it looks like it doesn't rely on PATH as I believed, but rather on its ./configure settings (--prefix, --build and so on).

Mine, with  `--prefix=/usr`, --build=x86_64-suse-linux, --program-suffix=-4.6`, looks for its components in (with respect to the directory where the`gcc` binary resides:
    - ../lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.6
    - ../lib64/gcc/
    - ../lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.6/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/x86_64-suse-linux/4.6/
    - ../lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.6/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/

(checked with `strace`).

Were a binary from another gcc present in one of those directories, it would get invoked instead of the 'correct' one.

Try checking with `gcc -v` (or with `strace`) to see which `as` is being run.

Comment: The path shown in makefile is the one to the installed package (as it should be). What other paths to check? And how to check 'flags' ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seeing your edit, flags are probably OK, but I'm afraid that the invocation of the various "pieces" of the compiler might go to the wrong instance of `as`. Check the value of the PATH environment variable. In a pinch, temporarily place the bin directory of the desired gcc before anything else in your PATH.

Comment: @Iserni None of my PATHs has any reference to gcc or assembly (I used printenv command)

Comment: I see. What is the result using the other, gcc 4.0?

Comment: That is a long log from strace. I went directly to gcc 4.0.2 directory in /usr/local/ Providing [link](http://pastebin.com/uFbGmL14)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15719/discussion-between-lserni-and-peter-kowalski)

Answer (score 0):

If someone still needs to run bounds checking with this ancient gcc version:
The best you can do is to tell it to pass the relevant argument to the assembler with `-Wa,--32`, so you would need this:

```
error: error.c
    /usr/local/gcc-4.0.2/bin/gcc -fbounds-checking -Wa,--32 -g -Wall -pedantic $< -o $@
```

Background info: your ancient gcc generates 32 bit assembly while your modern assembler defaults to 64 bit. This is not a problem for most of the instructions as generally the 32 bit register operations are there in 64 bit mode, push and pop are exceptions: they do not support 32 bit operands in 64 bit mode.